# Loopback: how to configure Nginx?

Tags: node.js, nginx, loopbackjs

I am trying to deploy Loopback on production but I am not able to configure nginx properly.

This is my nginx config file:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:8080 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/root-folder-of-my-project;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

And this is my config.json:

```
{
  "restApiRoot": "/api",
  "host": "0.0.0.0",
  "port": 3000,
  "remoting": {
    "context": false,
    "rest": {
      "handleErrors": false,
      "normalizeHttpPath": false,
      "xml": false
    },
    "json": {
      "strict": false,
      "limit": "100kb"
    },
    "urlencoded": {
      "extended": true,
      "limit": "100kb"
    },
    "cors": false
  }
}
```

I have tried to change the port in config.json to 8000, 8080 as well as the Nginx config to 3000.

When I simply execute server/server.js on the terminal I am getting the message that the webserver is running. However when I add server.js to pm2, I am not able to open the project in the browser.

I have also ensured that /var/www/root-folder-of-my-project; is indeed the path to the root of my project.

Is there something wrong in my configuration?

Comment: Hi, I am setuping my VPS with nginx, I am not sure what i need to setup for the ' /var/www/root-folder-of-my-project'  I have setted the path of my dist folder but doesn't work

Comment: I am unsrue if the root matters here as the proxy pass is used. make sure your project is running in the background with for example pm2

Comment: Thanks for your help, looks like the root doesn't matter :) I had an issue on my project I was able to fix it with the logs of PM2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ufw is blocking the connection on port 3000. Enable the port like so:

```
ufw allow 3000/tcp
```